# nodejs process.env variables not working in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Created a nodejs lambda function locally and integrated dotenv, so that env variables are accessed using process.env method. It is working. While deploying the same lambda and when tested inside aws console, it is returning undefined for env variable. Any idea why it so.

Comment: are you using serverless? did make sure to add the environment variables to the Lambda function?

Comment: not using any serverless frameworks..added dotenv package for using process.env and it is working locally. After deployment it to aws(uploading zip to S3), it is showing undefined for env variables.

Comment: is the env variable set when you open the lambda via the aws console https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda ? How do you deploy the lambda (CloudFormation, manually...)?

Answer (score 1):

Download your deployment zip file from S3 and make sure it has the `.env` file.

Comment: zip file is just a collection of node packages and it has the dotenv package too

Comment: I'm talking about the `.env` FILE not the the package or the node_modules folder.

Comment: hi @roby.elan can you accept my answer if it fixed the issue of you? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention in Environment variables at Lambda.

[image: Edit to add the variables in Lambda]

either if you are using server-less template to deploy , mentioned under '**Environment**'

```
# serverless.yml

 provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  environment:
   envOne: 12345678

 functions:
  myFunction:
  environment:
   envTwo: 87654321
```

Reference : https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.2.0

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps: you need to **specify the environment variable in lambda function section of the `template.yaml` file as well**. Example:

```
requestRetrievalFunction:
 ...
 Properties:
  ...
  Environment:
        Variables:
          EMAILS_TABLE: !Ref EmailsTable
          TIME_TO_EXPIRE: 20
  ...
```

In my particular case I am using two env variables (`EMAILS_TABLE` and `TIME_TO_EXPIRE`). For local testing I defined them in the `env.json` file too:

```
{
    "requestRetrievalFunction": {
        "EMAILS_TABLE": "nico-ppot",
        "TIME_TO_EXPIRE": 30
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case AWS and Google Cloud Platform not allow us to use some keywords name in the variable environnement like :

```
not ok :  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXX"
ok : CLOUD_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXX"
not ok : AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "XXX"
ok CLOUD_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "XXX"
```